# p:media PDF data content disappears after any ajax event on the same view in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, media

PrimeFaces media tag displayed the PDF content properly on the page load. But when I click download link on the same page the report content on the object tag has disappeared. The Object tag is displaying with blank content. This problem occurs only in IE. Is there any solution for this problem?

```
    <h:form id="reportResultPageForm">
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" showSummary="true"
layout="table" style="width:100%;" />

<p:panel id="panel" header="Help File Uploader"
styleClass="centeredPanelGrid">
<h:panelGrid column="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

<h:commandLink immediate="true">
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" width="24" />
<p:fileDownload value="#{reportResultBean.stream}" />
</h:commandLink>

</h:panelGrid>
<p:media value="#{reportResultBean.stream}" cache="false"
height="600" style="width:100%;" player="pdf">
</p:media>
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

```java
    @ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ReportResultBean {


public StreamedContent getStream() {

BaseReportSearchCriteria brsc = new BaseReportSearchCriteria();

StreamedContent stream = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(
generateReport.generateReport(brsc)), "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");

return stream;
}
}
```

Comment: This problem is still accurate today, I'm having the same issue in my application